# Is that bechamel that Gordon Ramsay is adding to the lasagna?

Tags: lasagna, bechamel

In [this video](https://youtu.be/Zmtmzj6Klj0?t=34s), you can see Gordan Ramsay piping a white substance into his lasagna.

Recently saw a post about substitute for ricotta or cottage in a lasagna. Several members agreed that bechamel is traditionally used.

So is that what Ramsay is doing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gordon says *"white sauce"*, which is a simpler term for bechamel-based sauces and is quite common when making lasagna.

Yet the stuff that gets stirred in the bowl looks somewhat "fluffier" than classic bechamel and when it's piped has a "raggedness" that plain bechamel doesn't have, but smoother that pure ricotta.

My conclusion: it's hard to say for certain, but *to me* it looks like a mixture of both.

Comment: If you google "Gordon Ramsay Lasagna" you will find a recipe (assuming it is similar to the video) where he makes a bechamel, then adds cheddar cheese.  The added cheese would certainly change the texture.

Comment: @moscafj just watched again: there is finely grated cheese (parmesan?) amongst the mise en place, yet the sauce is too smooth for grated cheddar - that would have to be grated *extremely* fine. Still unclear to me. Watched a video about G's lasagne al forno - the bechamel looks quite different.

Answer (score -1):

It's the same recipe of bechamel, the only difference is that he adds cheddar cheese.